# Is there a way to test if a React component is within another component of a particular type?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Let's for a second assume we have 3 components.

```
export class ComponentA extends React.Component<IComponentAProps, IComponentAState>{
    constructor(props: Readonly<IComponentAProps>) {
        super(props)
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <ComponentB />
        );
    }
}

export class ComponentB extends React.Component<IComponentBProps, IComponentBState>{
    constructor(props: Readonly<IComponentBProps>) {
        super(props)
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <ComponentC />
        );
    }
}

export class ComponentC extends React.Component<IComponentBProps, IComponentBState>{
    constructor(props: Readonly<IComponentBProps>) {
        super(props)
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <ComponentA />
        );
    }
}
```

Now obviously this is going to cause an infinite loop. Is there a way for me to check in ComponentC to see whether or not it is ultimately contained within an instance of ComponentA?

Comment: Looks like bad design, what goal are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Yeah it's bad design here and not actually indicative of what I'm building, it just easily demonstrated the issue. Essentially I have an auditing component, and it needs to set a global context. But I need to be careful that there isn't another auditing component inside another, and if there is I want the parent to be the auditing context. The concern is that some dev might come along and unknowingly nest them which would cause issues for the audit.

Comment: At runtime, or compile time? The thing is that a recursive component hierarchy isn't intrinsically bad--it's only bad if there's no end condition, like anything recursive.

Comment: Wouldn't such scenario automatically throws `RangeError` at runtime even during development? Why do you need to manually check?

Comment: Either runtime or compile time would be fine honestly. Compile time would be nice to prevent devs from doing it, runtime is fine in that I could write some logic to handle it.

Comment: @Matt My point was that determining "bad" vs "good" recursive hierarchies depends on understanding what "bad" and "good" mean, which depends on context and (possible) run-time behavior. One trivial way to solve for a simple case would be to stick a context wrapper around the problematic component and do something like increment a counter in that context each time the component is used. If > n there's a potential problem.

Comment: @Dave Newton Yeah perhaps my example is a bit too simplistic for what I'm looking for. Essentially I just want to be able to write some code that can check to see if one component is the child of another particular type of component, but the nature of React has barriers preventing me from going up the chain. I might have to think outside the box and implement some sort of locking feature for what I want if I can't just do a check and ignore.

Comment: @Matt That's what a context would provide: a way of understanding, relatively unobtrusively, that something already exists.

Comment: Yeah contexts seem like what I need to work on. I can simply check the context on componentDidMount and handle what I need to do there. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this is what you need, but you can achieve this using a [React context](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext).

```js
import React, { createContext, FunctionComponent, useContext, useEffect } from 'react';

export const TopDogContext = createContext<string>('');

// The top dog can never be nested!
export const TopDog: FunctionComponent = ({ children }) => {
  const aboveMe = useContext(TopDogContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (aboveMe) {
      setTimeout(() => alert('Yo, you can\'t nest me!'));
      throw new Error('Yo, you can\'t nest me!');
    }
  }, [aboveMe]);

  return (
    <TopDogContext.Provider value={'I\'m the top dog!'}>
      { children }
    </TopDogContext.Provider>
  )
};


// -------
import { TopDog } from './top-dog';

function App() {
  <TopDog>
    <div className="App">
      [... YOUR APP HERE ...]
      {/* Will create an error if uncommented */}
      {/* <TopDog /> */}
    </div>
  </TopDog>
}
```

Note that you can still have multiple `<TopDog>`, but they will never have one being the ancestor of another.

Comment: Note: you can also just pass down the same value as the parent context instead of throwing an error. This way, only one value is created.

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Thank you.